# How to initialize zClip on click of a button

Tags: jquery, zclip

For zClip instead of initializing it as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

Is is possible to initialize on click of a button? If yes then how it can be done.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939506/zclip-issue-when-assigning-it-to-multiple-links-in-hidden-divs

Answer (score 0):

Include the zlicp js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.zclip.min.js"></script>
```

HTML markup:

```
<textarea id="text-to-copy"></textarea>
<button id="copy-button">Copy</button>

<script>
$(function () {
    $('#copy-button').zclip({
        path: 'ZeroClipboard.swf',
        copy: function() { return $('#text-to-copy').val(); }
    });
});
</script>
```

Two things you need to be aware of

1. zclip uses a swf Flash to overlap the  or  which triggers the clipboard copy. It might not work with file://, but it'll work in a local site.
2. Sometimes, zclip doesn't position the overlap flash -  correctly. You need to adjust the position manually.